# Laravel Product Attributes with multiple Values

Tags: database, laravel, attributes, e-commerce

I'm struggling with the (at first hand) simple issue of product attributes and variants for like 2-3 days now, Google searches doesn't lead me to anything that pin point my use case so I decided it's time I try to look for help here..

These are the tables that I was planning for the initial structure..
[image]

But I seem to be missing something here, because now when I try to setup the UI for adding attributes and variations I come to the conclusion that it will be hard to map attributes with values on product to product basis on the frontend later..

This is the UI I am trying to build for adding the variants and attributes to a product:
[image]

Then in variations you will have available only the attributes that are marked to be used in variations, and the only values that they accept should be the attribute values picked for the product, which looks like this:
[image]

So now that you know the use case, do you see any problems with the DB Design, because I don't like the 2 separate linking tables for attributes and for values, and also the 2 more for variants, but I can't wrap my head around another working example, and I don't thing that having json column for values will do it, becuase the variations are dependable of the product values..

Comment: Any chance to edit question and repost image of table structure avoiding overlapping of relations lines? I am sure question will get much more attraction that way: help us to help you.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for the advice, and can you check if that's better? :)